# Google Form not emailing when changing subject variable

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm pretty new to Google scripting or scripting in general.  I used the following to send the information input by the user into one email to a specific email address.  what I wanted to do was to have it take the 3rd row as the subject line (in this case it's the name).  This is the script I have in the spreadsheet the Form is linked to:

```
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  try 
  {      
    // You may replace this with another email address
    var email = "dyingkingdomsrecords@gmail.com";
    var subject = row[3];
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
        message += key + e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
      }
    }

    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp for HTML Mail.

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

When I don't have a subject variable or put in a string for it I get the email no problem.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column name in the sheet is "Name", you can add this line before the MailApp.sendEmail method.

```
var subject = e.namedValues["Name"].toString();
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```